# Ansible - use with_items and with_sequence at the same time

Tags: loops, sequence, roles, ansible

Is there any way to make a part of role like this:
I need to run five times commands that are in the nrpe.cfg (there 5 commands in the config file - so 5 x 5 commands) ?

```
- name: grep the commands from nagios
  shell: grep -R check_http_ /etc/nagios/nrpe.cfg | cut -d= -f2-
  register: nagios_check
- name: check_before
  shell: (printf $(echo '{{ item }}' | awk -F'country=' '{print $2}' | cut -d'&' -f1); printf ' ';{{ item }} | cut -d ' ' -f-2) >> {{ ansible_env.DATA_LOG }}/eden-{{ dateext.stdout }}
  register: checkedenbefore
  with_items: "{{ nagios_check.stdout_lines }}"
  **with_sequence: count=5**
  ignore_errors: True
```

Comment: since ansible version 2.1 loop control is in place. with this feature you can rename, the items you iterate over. therefore inner and outer items are accessable. see https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_loops.html#loop-control for this hf

Answer (score 1):

This is currently not possible but should again be with the release of Ansible 2.0. With Ansible 2 you can use `with_items` together with `include`, so you will be able to have your `check_before` task which has the `with_sequence` loop inside a separate yml file and then include it together with `with_items`.

Something along these lines:

**main.yml**:

```
- name: grep the commands from nagios
  shell: grep -R check_http_ /etc/nagios/nrpe.cfg | cut -d= -f2-
  register: nagios_check
- include: check_before.yml
  with_items: "{{ nagios_check.stdout_lines }}"
```

**check_before.yml**:

```
- name: check_before
  shell: (printf $(echo '{{ item }}' | awk -F'country=' '{print $2}' | cut -d'&' -f1); printf ' ';{{ item }} | cut -d ' ' -f-2) >> {{ ansible_env.DATA_LOG }}/eden-{{ dateext.stdout }}
  register: checkedenbefore
  with_sequence: count=5
  ignore_errors: True
```

I don't know when Ansible 2 will be released, but you could use the [devel branch from github](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/tree/devel) and see if it fits your needs.

Comment: the main issue in your answer is that it's not a single role. So basically there is no "clean" way to repeat a task (x times) that has "with_items"?

Comment: Not sure what that does mean: it's not a single role

Comment: In your answer you used 2 roles: main.yml and check_before.yml not one

Comment: Those are files, not roles. You can have as many files in a role as you want. The `include` statement only includes files.

Comment: I understand, but what I wanted is all in one file. I don't like to maintain "n" files. Thanks

Comment: @ady8531 you should read up on the [best practices](http://docs.ansible.com/playbooks_best_practices.html) and then rethink how you structure your roles.

Answer (score 1):

You can use with_nested.

```
- name: grep the commands from nagios
  shell: grep -R check_http_ /etc/nagios/nrpe.cfg | cut -d= -f2-
  register: nagios_check

- name: check_before
  shell: (printf $(echo '{{ item.0 }}' | awk -F'country=' '{print $2}' | cut -d'&' -f1); printf ' ';{{ item.0 }} | cut -d ' ' -f-2) >> {{ ansible_env.DATA_LOG }}/eden-{{ dateext.stdout }}
  register: checkedenbefore
  with_nested:
   - "{{ nagios_check.stdout_lines }}"
   - "{{ range(0, 5) }}"
  ignore_errors: True
```